# format a bibliography style file to add an en-dash before journal name

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using `natbib` for my bibliographies. I am going to be submitting to a journal which requires an en-dash before the journal name, e.g.,

```
Haila, Y. and Järvinen, O. 1983. Land bird communities on a Finnish island: 
species impoverishment and abundance patterns. – Oikos 41: 255-273.
```

I have been using a modified version of the [evolution.bst](https://schneider.ncifcrf.gov/ftp/evolution.bst) bibliography style file but have not yet been able to figure out how to make this change. I think that the section of the file that needs to modified is:

```
FUNCTION {format.journal.eid}
{ eid "eid" bibinfo.check
duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
{ swap$ duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
  {
      ":" *
  }
  if$ 
 swap$ * 
}
 if$

}
```

But if I modify this section there doesn't appear to be any changes to the output. I thought it would just involve changing the line:

```
 {"--" swap$ *}
```

Any thoughts appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Make a copy of `evolution.bst` and call the copy, say, `evolution-dash.bst`.
- Open the file `evolution-dash.bst` in a text editor. (The editor you use for your main tex file will do fine.)
- In `evolution-dash.bst`, find the function `article`. (In my copy of this file, the function starts on line 933.)
- In the `article` function, about a dozen lines from the top, locate the following line:

  ```
        "journal" bibinfo.check
  ```

  Replace this line with

  ```
        "-- " swap$ * "journal" bibinfo.check
  ```

  i.e., insert the string `"-- " swap$ *` at the start of the line. (
- Save the file `evolution-dash.bst` either in the directory where the main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, replace the instruction `\bibliographystyle{evolution}` with `\bibliographystyle{evolution-dash}`. Then, rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!